# How to move the same item in list boxes

Tags: visual-studio-2010

hello there can you help me to list item to another listbox?
example
listbox1
apple 
banana 
cake
banana

then it will go to
lisbox2
banana
banana

it only transfer to listbox2 same name or integer anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should have same id for both same names. But id's cannot be same